# Service account i keyvault got locked

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, service-accounts

We noticed that our service account in one of our key vault was locked and we do not know why or who locked it. Is there a way for us to check logs or investigate why it got locked

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you have enabled logging on key vault, if so you should be able to access it from storage account. Some information about key vault logging is also available within Azure Monitor. Check following link for details. [Azure Key Vault Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging?tabs=Vault)

If you want you can use tools like log analytics to interrogate the data you have stored within the storage account.

Comment: Thank you! I was using log analytics data but I can only dig up to keyvault and can’t go deeper the service account

Comment: any account level activity should also be stored within AAD logs  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs